# Java - logic error getting value from an arrayList and using the index

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, runtime-error

my problem is this logic error everything else in the class works expect this part. 
just before here the user enters a value which corresponds to a value in the basket ArrayList.
i want to find the index of where this value is stored and return that to the main method to remove it. at the moment it is returning the user input not the target index. it compiles clean. thank you for taking the time

```
        //loop for each index within basket
      for (Integer indexBasket : basket){

        //if value at index = what we want to remove
       if (basket.get(indexBasket).equals(remove))

              {
       //then assign the value of posistion in the array to targetIndex
               targetIndex = indexBasket;
              }

          }
       }

  //return targetIndex
  return targetIndex;
}
```

Comment: there should be a `break;` following `targetIndex = indexBasket`. No point in traversing further if you already found what you need. Or just `return indexBasket;` in the loop.

Comment: @klarki maybe he wants to return the last one which matches

Comment: true, the List can contain duplicates. but in that case it would make sense to traverse from the end.

Comment: @klarki OK, good point, agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    //loop for each index within basket
      for (int indexBasket=0; indexBasket<basket.size(); indexBasket++){

        //if value at index = what we want to remove
       if (basket.get(indexBasket).equals(remove))

              {
       //then assign the value of posistion in the array to targetIndex
               targetIndex = indexBasket;
              }

          }
       }

  //return targetIndex
  return targetIndex;
}
```

If you check the doc here:
 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29
 
I think you will see what was wrong with your code. You were 
looping through the elements but were using them as indices.

Comment: that solved it. thank you so much for the fast response aswell :)